# Printing response result in array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using an API call  using php curl. In case of an decline I get these two type of responses;

1. In case transaction declined due to invalid number

   {
       "result": "ERROR",
       "message": "Transaction Declined: Invalid Card Number"
   }
2. When any fields are missing

   {
       "result": "ERROR",
       "message": {
           "address": "is a required field",
           "city": "is a required field",
           "state": "is a required field"
       }
   }

On API processing file, I store this error in session, so on error handling page, I am using following code

```
foreach($_SESSION['error_message'] as $x => $x_value) {
    echo ucfirst($x) . "&nbsp;" . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
```

This way in case of missing fields error everything is shown properly. But in case of case 1 when card is declined its not showing the response with the code above, but if I just echo

```
   echo $_SESSION['error_message'];
```

It will show the error response. I was wondering if there is a better way to handle this, so both the errors can be shown.

Comment: cast it to an array before you save it in session.

Comment: just check whether `message` is a string or an array first, if its an array, its variant 2, if its not its variant 1 (which is just a string, then no need for any foreach), a simple `if else` should suffice, my comment should give you an idea

Comment: @Ghost you mean to check the variable using is_string if its string or array? any better way or its just fine?

Answer (score 0):

Test to see if `$data->message` is an array or a string and then either do your `foreach` or just set the error message directly.  Would be better to have the errors on required fields as a simple array of strings, make the format of the object closer to what the transaction declined message is, if you have control over how that JSON is generated...

ie -

```
{ "result": "ERROR", "message": { "address is a required field", "city is a required field", "state is a required field" } }
```

And

`{ "result": "ERROR", "message": { "Transaction Declined: .... " }` }

```
<?php

$json1='{ "result": "ERROR", "message": "Transaction Declined: Invalid Card Number" }';

$json2='{ "result": "ERROR", "message": { "address": "is a required field", "city": "is a required field", "state": "is a required field" } }';


$obj=json_decode($json2);


if(is_object($obj->message)){
    foreach($obj->message as $k=>$v){
        $msg['error'][]="The field $k is a required field <br />";
    }
}else{
    $msg['error'][]=$obj->message;
}


print_r($msg);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function to accept either string or array and process it:

```
<?php

function storeError($message) {
  if(!isset($_SESSION['error_message'])) {
    $_SESSION['error_message'] = array();
  }

  if(is_array($message)) {
    $_SESSION['error_message'] = array_merge($_SESSION['error_message'], $message);
  } else {
    $_SESSION['error_message'][] = $message;
  }
}

storeError('test');
storeError(array(
    "address" => "is a required field",
    "city"=> "is a required field",
    "state" => "is a required field"
    ));
print_r($_SESSION['error_message']);

====>
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [address] => is a required field
    [city] => is a required field
    [state] => is a required field
)
```